# How to concat values with same key from JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working on a project where I want to build tokens from a JSON Array.

```
       //Data fed to the system       
      {"Fruits":[{"Number":"111", "Name":"Apple"}, {"Number":"112", "Name":"Orange"},{"Number":"113", "Name":"Peach"}]}

      //serializes the http content to a string
      string result = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

      //deserializes result
      Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(result);

      //builds custom tokens
      var customTokens = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      foreach (var dataField in data)
      {
        if (dataField.Value is JArray)
            {
                string nameValue = "";
                foreach (JObject content in dataField.Value.Children<JObject>())
                {
                    foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
                    {
                        nameValue += prop.Name.ToString() + " : " + prop.Value.ToString();
                    }

                }
                customTokens.Add($"{dataField.Key}", nameValue);
            }
        }
```

The above code managed to create token $Fruits.
But i also want to achieve token $Number and $Name, where values of each token is from the concatenated values of same key. Example, If I use the "$Number", it will be replaced by 111, 112, 113 and If I use the $Name, it will be replaced by Apple, Orange, Peach.

Also, I'm not using any strongly type models as I don't know what data will be fed to the system.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand your required output, can you clarify at all?

Comment: I want to concatenate the values of same key, so that when i used the "Number" i get the values such as 111, 112, 113

Comment: But where does the key  `Fruits` come in? You're just ignoring that at present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few minor changes to your code to achieve this. First make your dictionary look like this:

```
var customTokens = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Then, when you loop over all the properties in the array, check if the property has been added, and if not add it.

```
foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
{
    if(customTokens.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
    {
        customTokens[prop.Name].Add(prop.Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        customTokens.Add(prop.Name, new List<string> { prop.Value.ToString() });
    }
}
```

At the end you have a dictionary where the key is the property name and the value is a `List<string>` - this can be concatenated together:

```
foreach(var item in customTokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":" + String.Join(",", item.Value));
}
```

Or, if you *really* want it in a dictionary of concatenated strings just do this

```
var finalResult = customTokens.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => String.Format(",",v.Value));
```

Note you'll need to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file to use `ToDictionary`

Final test code:

```
var result = "{ \"Fruits\":[{\"Number\":\"111\", \"Name\":\"Apple\"}, {\"Number\":\"112\", \"Name\":\"Orange\"},{\"Number\":\"113\", \"Name\":\"Peach\"}]}";
Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(result);
var customTokens = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var dataField in data)
{
    if (dataField.Value is JArray)
    {         
        foreach (JObject content in dataField.Value.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
            {
                if(customTokens.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    customTokens[prop.Name].Add(prop.Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    customTokens.Add(prop.Name, new List<string> { prop.Value.ToString() });
                }
            }

        }

        foreach(var item in customTokens)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":" + String.Join(",", item.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to achieve.